# API route prefix with a value of post data

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-routing

Is it possible to have a dynamic API route prefix whose value is based on the `organization` field from post request data?

For instance, the post request data is:

```
id: 1, name: 'John Doe', organization: 'CISCO'
```

What I wanted in my route is:

```
Route::prefix('CISCO')->group(function() {
    Route::post('create', [Controller::class, 'create'];
})
```

And if it is not possible, is there any other way to pass the `organization` value so that I will be able to structure a dynamically prefixed route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, `CISCO` is a parameter in your URL.

You can do this:

```php
Route::prefix('{organization}')->group(function() {
    Route::post('create', [Controller::class, 'create'];
});
```

Which leads to this route:

`POST http://youdomain.com/CISCO/create`

Then in your controller:

```php
public function create($organization)
{
    dd($organization); //CISCO
}
```

---

Be careful with prefixes like this, since it can lead to routing problems. For instance, if you have another route like this:

```php
Route::prefix('{organization}')->group(function() {
    Route::post('create', [Controller::class, 'create'];
});

Route::prefix('{shop}')->group(function() {
    Route::post('create', [ShopController::class, 'create'];
});
```

Laravel will have a hard time to understand which route it should use.

The good practice here is to add another prefix, so it looks like this:

```php
Route::prefix('organization/{organization}')->group(function() {
    Route::post('create', [Controller::class, 'create'];
});

Route::prefix('shop/{shop}')->group(function() {
    Route::post('create', [ShopController::class, 'create'];
});
```

Also, keep in mind that using prefixes is useful when you have multiple routes using it. If you only have one route, you should only do something like this:

```php
Route::post('organization/{organization}/create', [Controller::class, 'create'];
Route::post('shop/{shop}/create', [ShopController::class, 'create'];
```

Comment: Thanks @toyi, as of now I cannot upvote because of my low reputation. will accept this answer in 4mins.

Comment: Thank you! Glad it solves your problem. I've updated my answer with some additional information that might be useful to you. Have a nice day :)